# Duplicate smart object inside element

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, mockup

To be more specific, I'm working on some posters project, and I need mockups. I have one showing one A3 frame with one smart object inside. 
Now I need mockups for set of 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 posters. I've tried to make one for set of 3 posters, I duplicated original frame, and when I positioned the first poster and saved, it was shown on all 3 frames. I've tried not duplicating but copying (New Smart Object via copy) smart object and placing it into other 2 frames but with no success.
I'm pretty sure this can be done, but I just don't know how. Any help welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I can't really work out what you are asking (perhaps I'm too stupid).  Do you want to use one smart object in all the documents, so that for example when you edit the smart object, it updates in all the documents?

Comment: Or maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have downloaded mockup frame (one frame). It has smart object and works fine with one poster. Now, I want to use that one frame, to make another brand new document, which will show set of 3 posters one next to another. So I will copy the original frame, but don't know how to make smart objects, so they don't update image on all 3 frames, because the 3 posters are different. Hope I cleared this now.

Comment: In the newest CC version of Photoshop, there are three ways to create smart objects - you can place linked PSDs as a smart object, or embed them, or create a smart object from within Photoshop.  Obviously linked objects will update over all the documents you have them inserted in.  I have to ask, do you really need to use smart objects for this? Quite honestly I don't see the benefit if all the posters are different.

Comment: I need to use smart objects as they are in original element, but I have found a way, answered below. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track... Not sure what you're doing wrong.

Right-click on your Smart Object layer and choose 'New Smart Object via copy'.

Double-click on the Smart Object layer thumbnail and place your individual images (File > Place...) behind your frame.

Now editing the contents of either the original or the copy should not affect the other. Here for example are the same frames created this way with different contents:

[image: Smart Object copies]

Comment: I think the problem is because the element has many layers, like different frames, mat, reflection etc. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/6fWm9YP 

When I duplicate group, editing contents reflects on all 3 frames. Don't know how to properly use 'New Smart Object via copy' in this particular situation, because of element being complex.

But I played around and found a way, I just drag an image an place it above smart object layer. Maybe not the proper way, but it works.

Comment: @Jimi If I'm following you - you've made three Groups with Smart Objects within. Your problem is that you're just triplicating the Group. You're not going to get new Smart Objects that way, just copies of the original Smart Object. Just do right-click, 'New Smart Object via copy' twice right inside the original Group. This will give you two new (and separate) Smart Objects. Then just drag those new Smart Objects one by one into your other two Groups and delete the ones that were created when copying the Group. Now you can edit your individual Smart Objects without affecting the others.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'm triplicating the Group with Smart Objects within. I also tried to copy original smart object and drag it into Group, but when I delete original SO within group, I get like transparent square between frames, guess it has something to do with positioning of SO in correspondence with frames (original SO is placed on left side, when I drag the copy of it into other group it stays on the left, while it should be centered and right). And as each element has its frames, mat, shadows, reflections and color settings, makes it more complex. I'm fine with drag 'n drop though.